# What is this cloud-with-sun icon meant to represent?

Tags: notification-bar

Can you tell me what this symbol is for?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which one? There is more than one here

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the "clouds" emblem, with the "sunrays" front-and-center? Maybe the icon for whatever weather-reporting app is part of your OS?

Comment: Yes the one with the cloud..in the middle

Comment: I'm assuming the icon on the left is an email notification, which means these icons were placed on the left side (app notifications), not right side (system notifications)? Is there a related notification when you open the notification panel?